# Install OpenMP on Mac OS X Lion Without Brew

Tags: macos, openmp, homebrew, cython

I am running an old version of Mac: Mac OS X Lion.
I do not want to upgrade to a newer: don't have time and neither the bandwidth for it.
Most of the tutorials on the Web on OpenMP for Mac, require the use of Homebrew.
My version of homebrew refuses to install anything because of some SSL (outdated curl version).
How can I install OpenMP (for use with Cython) on Mac OS X without brew?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my Brew issues by installing curl from source
after downloading the sources from:
https://curl.haxx.se/download.html
.
Then setting the target architecture to 10.8, typing configure and make install.
Now brew is working fine (for now)